# Find files that had been stored from a single text file

Tags: python

Is there any way for me to read file that I saved inside a text file using python?

For example I have a file called `filenames.txt`. The content of the file should have name of other files such as:

```
/home/ikhwan/acespc.c
/home/ikhwan/trloc.cpp
/home/ikhwan/Makefile.sh
/home/ikhwan/Readme.txt
```

So, theoretically what I want to do is I have a Python script to change some header of the file. So `filenames.txt` will act as a platform for me whenever I want to run the script to change only selected file. The reason is I have so many files inside directory and subdirectories and I just want python to read only the files that I put inside `filenames.txt` and only change that particular file. In the future, if I want to run the script on other files, I just can add or replace filenames in `filenames.txt`

So the flow of the script will be as follows:

Run script-->script start search for the filenames inside filenames.txt-->script will add or change header of the file.

Current, i used os.walk but it will search within all directory and subdirectory. Here are my current function.

```
def read_file(file):  
    skip = 0
    headStart = None
    headEnd = None
    yearsLine = None
    haveLicense = False
    extension = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
    logging.debug("File extension is %s",extension)
    type = ext2type.get(extension)
    logging.debug("Type for this file is %s",type)
    if not type:
        return None
    settings = typeSettings.get(type)
    with open(file,'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Comment: You have handed us a programming problem with no apparent attempt of your own.  It appears that you have not yet learned how to open and read a file.  This suggests that what you need some time with a local tutor or a walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: currently i used recursive function so that it will read all files from directory and subdirectories. here are my current code.

Comment: I've just edit the question and put my current function.

Comment: Much better; "close" vote retracted.

Comment: Wait, you want to read `filenames.txt` and then you want to read/edit each file that is stored as a path in `filenames.txt`?

Comment: Now ... where are you stuck?  What is the argument to `readfile`: "filenames.txt", or is this the function you plan to call for each file listed there?  I'm not sure, since I don't see any code to change a file header, or to loop through given file names.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to walk through the file system if you already have your file paths listed in the `filenames.txt`, just open it, read it line by line and then process each file path from it, e.g.

```
# this is your method that will be called with each file path from the filenames.txt
def process_file(path):
    # do whatever you want with `path` in terms of processing
    # let's just print it to STDOUT as an example
    with open(path, "r") as f:
        print(f.read())

with open("filenames.txt", "r") as f:  # open filenames.txt for reading
    for line in f:  # read filenames.txt line by line
        process_file(line.rstrip())  # send the path stored on the line to process_file()
```

Comment: is this still applicable if i change or add another path inside the file?

Comment: @Ikhwan - you can add/modify/remove file paths in your `filenames.txt` file at your leasure - whenever you run the above script the `process_file()` function will be called for each of those paths.

Comment: How can i open one of the file? For example i want to print all the content from acespc.c

Comment: @Ikhwan - the same way `filenames.txt` is opened, I've updated the `process_file()` function to print out the passed file's contents.